# How many ways to colorize the table

Tags: combinatorics

Each cell of a square table of 3 × 3 can be painted black, white or red. How many different colorings of this table? If we do not consider the turnings of the board, we get $3^9$ variants. How many variants of coloring will be, if you consider the possibility of turning the board?

I can sort through all the options for a 2 × 2 table and two colors (16 variants without rotation and 6 variants with turns), but for 3 × 3 variants too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma). You take a group, in this case the group of rotations of a square: $0, 90, 180, 270$ degree rotations, and look at which colourings are fixed by each rotation. The formula is

> $$ \frac{1}{\text{size of group}}\left( \text{colourings fixed by the first group element} + \text{colourings fixed by the second group element} + \cdots \right) $$

In this case

- $3^9$ colourings are fixed by a $0$ degree rotation
- $3^3$ colourings are fixed by a $90$ or $270$ degree rotation (such colourings are determined by how the top-left, top-centre and centre squares are coloured)
- $3^5$ colourings are fixed by a $180$ degree rotation (determined by the top three squares and the centre-left and centre squares)

Applying Burnside's Lemma, there are

$$ \frac14 \left( 3^9 + 2 \cdot 3^3 + 3^5 \right) = 4995 $$

distinct colourings.

Comment: Page 30 of lecture note http://www.ist.tugraz.at/aichholzer/teaching/eca/eca2017.pdf helped me to understand your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the number of "essentially different" colorings, then you may want to note that in the $2 \times 2$ table with two colors considering rotations is enough, but in general, there are 8 [symmetries of the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_groups#The_symmetry_group_of_a_square:_dihedral_group_of_order_8).

Besides the rotations by multiples of 90 degrees, there are four "flips:" horizontal, vertical, and along the two main diagonals. The method described by @TrevorGunn still applies, but you also need to compute the number of colorings that are fixed under each flip, which turns out to be $3^6$ for each flip.  All in all,

$$ \frac{3^9 + 2 \cdot 3^3 + 3^5 + 4 \cdot 3^6}{8} = 2862 \enspace. $$

For the $2 \times 2$ table with two colors, there are $2^2$ colorings fixed under horizontal and vertical flips, and $2^3$ colorings that are fixed under diagonal flips.  Compared to rotations only, the four flips double both numerator and denominator, leaving the final number of colorings unchanged:

$$ \frac{2^4 + 2 \cdot 2^1 + 2^2 + 2 \cdot 2^2 + 2 \cdot 2^3}{8} = 6 \enspace. $$

Finally, note that you cannot apply Burnside's lemma to flips only, because, unlike rotations, they do not form a group (they are not closed under composition).